# Nextgen and Flexslider of Beresponzive theme

Tags: wordpress, flexslider

I have an issue with Nextgen plugin. When activated it cause a white screen at my slider area. When deactivated the slider starts working again. When i login to wordpress dashboard and preview my site, it works good with nextgen. and by log out it goes back to same white screen at slider area. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add a proper code snippet and screenshot.

Comment: link to my site http://www.sdukp.gov.pk/ nextgen is activated.

Comment: slider area is white